# jQuery datepicker start date interval not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, weekday

I use jQuery datepicker for showing users available days and wants to disable and mark red busy days. I use for this **beforeShowDay** datepicker option:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';

            for (var i=0; i < busyStarts.length; i++) {
                var busyStart = new Date(busyStarts[i]);
                var busyEnd = new Date(busyEnds[i]);
                if (date >= busyStart && date <= busyEnd) {
                    cssClass = 'ui-state-disabled busy_date';
                }
            }

            return [true, cssClass];
        }
```

**busyStarts** and **busyEnds** variables are:

[image]

But I see this result:

[image]

the first days of intervals are not selected. Why? I have condition **date >= busyStart**

When I looked into debugger:
[image]

That's why equal (=) condition didn't work. Start and End dates with time 03:00:00 but date with 00:00:00 and when dates the same **date** <= at the same day because 00:00:00 < 03:00:00.

Now I ask, WHY? And how to resolve this correct?

Comment: If you use a debugger and break on that expression, does your CSS string get a value for 9-24 -> 9-30?

Comment: Interesting situation when I look in the debugger: busyEnd
 Date {Fri Aug 31 2012 03:00:00 GMT+0300}
 
busyStart
 Date {Fri Aug 10 2012 03:00:00 GMT+0300}. But date
 Date {Sat Aug 11 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300}

Comment: Why start and end dates with 03:00:00 ? :) And date with 00:00:00. That's why = conditions is not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESOLVED

I have changed my code. Added setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) to start and end dates initialization.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';

            for (var i=0; i < busyStarts.length; i++) {
                var busyStart = new Date(busyStarts[i]).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var busyEnd = new Date(busyEnds[i]).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                if (date >= busyStart && date <= busyEnd) {
                    cssClass = 'ui-state-disabled busy_date';
                }
            }

            return [true, cssClass];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting that solution!  I'm actually actively developing using the DatePicker and if I run into your situation, it will be nice to know where to look first!

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';

        for (var i=0; i < busyStarts.length; i++) {
            var date = new Date(date),
                busyStart = new Date(busyStarts[i]),
                busyEnd = new Date(busyEnds[i]);
            if (date.getTime() >= busyStart.getTime() && date.getTime() <= busyEnd.getTime()) {
                cssClass = 'ui-state-disabled busy_date';
            }
        }

        return [true, cssClass];
    }
```

getTime() converts your Date object to the time passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC in milisecond. This gives you an integer that you can easily compare.

Comment: Yes, but in my case this will produce the same error. Because timestamps will be different in 3 hours as with simple Date objects comparing.

Comment: ok, sorry then, when I didn't get the question right. Happy you solved it yourself though.